# Header is not showing full width in WordPress

Tags: css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap in WordPress. Header is with background image. but it is not showing full width. I tested the code outside the WordPress. it was showing header with full width but not in WordPress.

```css
.header-container {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  height: 326px;
  width: 100%;
}

.background-image {
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <div class="header-container text-center background-image" style="background-image: url(<?php header_image(); ?>);">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

please check the screenshot from the following links for reference

with WordPress header is not showing full width with background image:
[with WordPress Header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sRf2E.png)!

but ,without WordPress code is showing header with full width: 
[without WordPress Header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6I79Y.png)!

Comment: not full width becuase you have `class="container"` container in bootstrap is equal to `padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;`

Comment: can you give us a link to the site, we need to see all the CSS. since it's a wordpress site, am sure there is CSS that are affecting to your code

Comment: you should use container-fluid if you want a full width row.   check it and let us know!

Answer (score -1):

Try changing .header-container class to:

```
.header-container{
   display: inline-block;
   position: relative;
   height: 326px;
   width: 100%;
}
```